# JSON View Formatting - Count total number of items in SP list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, json-formatting, grouping, customization

I want to modify the groups footer of a custom view that is grouped by a metadata column named Response/Actionv2. In the Totals section of the view settings I enabled *Count* for this column, which now displays the number of items (rows) for each of the groups.

However, I would like to use this number in the JSON formatting to calculate and display the proportion (in percentage %) of total number of decisions. As you can see in the code below, I've included the static number 31, but I'd like to be able to dynamically reference the total number of items in the list?

Basically, do you have an idea on how to implement this formula:

```
(@columnAggregate.value / TOTAL NUMBER OF ITEMS) * 100.
```

Here is the JSON code I came up with:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": {
    "hideFooter": false,
    "footerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "attributes": {
            "iconName": "CalculatorPercentage"
          },
          "style": {
            "color": "=if(@columnAggregate.type == 'Count' && @columnAggregate.value < 50, '#d13438', '#107c10')",
            "font-weight": "600",
            "margin-top": "10px"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "color": "=if(@columnAggregate.type == 'Count' && @columnAggregate.value < 50, '#d13438', '#107c10')",
            "font-weight": "600",
            "margin-top": "10px",
            "font-family": "Segoe UI"
          },
          "txtContent": {
            "operator": "*",
            "operands": [
              100,
              {
                "operator": "/",
                "operands": [
                  "@columnAggregate.value",
                  31
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not currently possible in List Formatting. You would only have access to the total count in the list footer but won't be able to reference it inside your group footers.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much for the response. I had done some tests and I had indeed found that by using @columnAggregate.value in footerFormatter of the list (and not a the group level), it was returning the correct value (total count of items) which is 31.

Comment: Does anyone know how to or know the code to placing totals to the top?